# Azure DevOps Running Ansible Playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, azure-devops

Currently I am having issues with Azure DevOps running Ansible task. The Ansible task would use the command module and run a command locally on itself calling the aws cli api. When Ansible calls the task and gets to the task of running the command module, an error message would show up saying that it cannot find the aws profile.

The error message, "The config profile (dev) could not be found", where dev is my aws profile. The strangest thing is if I were to run the command locally on the server, it work fine, but putting the command into Ansible would have the command fail.

I have made sure the user I am using and the command work and they both are correct. Used command, shell and raw modules, and none of these modules work.

This is the command I am able to run on the server itself, but not running through ansible.

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate file:///temp/live/"{{ domain_name }}"/cert.pem --certificate-chain file:///temp/live/"{{ domain_name }}"/chain.pem --private-key file:///tmp/live/"{{ domain_name }}"/privkey.pem --region us-east-1 --profile dev
```

Edit:

On Azure DevOps, I have tried using different users and checking sudo user on and off, none of these work.
I have tried not putting in aws profile in the command to run the playbook, does not work.
I have created a default aws profile so the aws command does not need to be specified, works if running on the terminal locally, does not work if putting into playbook

Comment: I assume you are using self hosted agent on Azure Devops for implementation, right ?

Comment: Please try with the file path with the full root folder

Comment: @error404Yes, I am using a self hosted agent

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT file path to the certs are with the full root folder so /tmp/live/test.com/privkey.pem is the full path to the cert

Comment: Do you install ansible in your self hosted agent?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Yes, i installed the ansible on my self hosted agent. I can run tasks on it where it connects to my remote servers and run the tasks, but I cant seem to run the aws cli locally though.